# How to make line break inside bootstrap progress bar in case, if text is wider than a div?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

1. By default progress bar shows text just inside the part which has some progress (if progress is 25%, the text can be shown just withing this 1/4 part). This can be fixed by `white-space: nowrap;`
2. How can be fixed the case without using js, when text is longer than `div`, ie how to apply something like `height: auto` in order to move some part of text to a new line?

```css
.my-case {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black !important;
}

.fix {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

By default
<div class="progress" style="width:100px">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">Some very very long text</div>
</div>

My case
<div class="progress my-case">
  <div class="progress-bar fix" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">Some very very long text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want the text to wrap say into 2+ lines?

Comment: Yes, I need to move some part of text to a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.progress-bar` should be made `position: absolute` with `height: 100%;` inside a `position:relative` parent  (our `.progress`) with `auto` height - in order to let the inner text/content dictate it's height.

The text should be than moved inside a separate element like i.e: `.progress-label`

```css
.progress {
  position:relative; /* add! */
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black !important;
  height: auto !important; /* add! (let text dictate height! ) */
}

.progress-bar { /* Added styles */
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

.progress-label { /* added element and CSS */
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  <span class="progress-label">Some very very long text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. In your example you can remove `fix` class.

Comment: @TitanFighter yes, you can remove it (I can remove it too) unless you use it for something else ;)